# iOS using SQLITE database. SQLITE_ROW returning 100 even with a limit set

Tags: ios, sqlite, limit

Using SQLite Database Browser, I can send a query:

"SELECT latitude, longitude FROM locations WHERE businessid = 1453 LIMIT 3;"

and I get three rows of data. Well for some reason in my app's code the SQLITE_ROW value is 100 determined by assigning it to an int and logging. So this makes some sort of infinite loop and the app freezes indefinitely. I would really like to know why this code works for other areas of my app where I'm reading in other tables but not here. Here is the code.

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < appDelegate.userList.count; i++) // for each location in the user list, add to surrounding data
    {
        RMLocationItem *temp = [appDelegate.userList objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *sqlStatement1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        sqlStatement1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT latitude, longitude FROM locations WHERE businessid = %d limit 5;", temp.businessId];
        const char *sqlStatement = [sqlStatement1  UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
         {
            //sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, temp.businessId);
            //int sr = SQLITE_ROW;
            //NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sr];
            //NSLog(myNewString);
            while( sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                double latitude = (double) sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 0);
                double longitude = (double) sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1);

                sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);


                RMLocationItem *newLocation = [[RMLocationItem alloc]initWithName: temp.nameOfPlace distance:0 Id:temp.businessId longitude:longitude latitude:latitude address:NULL city:NULL];

                [appDelegate.surroundingRestaurants addObject:newLocation];

            }
        }
        else  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

EDIT: Solved thank you, just like @rmaddy said, I took sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement); out and moved finalize up to just after the while loop.

Comment: Don't call `sqlite3_reset` inside the `while` loop. That's bad. You want to call `sqlite3_finalize` after the `while` loop.

Comment: And what do you mean that `SQLITE_ROW` value is 100? `SQLITE_ROW` is a constant with a value of `100`. This is what you should see.

Comment: God I need to just come here right away.. I've been spending hours on this. Thank you!

Comment: And now I learned more about SQLITE_ROW lol thank you @rmaddy, I saw a post somewhere about getting 100 versus 101. I just thought it was the number of rows returned by the query.

Comment: Go to the [SQLite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), navigate to the [C/C++ list of constants](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/constlist.html) and scan them a minute or two to become familiar with them.